# Why am I not able to return a view with ->withInput() and ->with() in Laravel

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-controller

Why am I not able to return a view with ->withInput() and ->with() in Laravel.

I want to show old input for user when user is making a search and also a flash message. But currently, it does not seems like I am able to do so.

Code example:

```php
return view('siteadmin.help.help', [
'articles' => $articles,
'categories' => $categories
])

// below is not working
->with('success', 'Hello world')
->withInput();
```

The hole class:

```php
class ArticlesSearchHelpCenterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        # via Facade
        $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'search_query' => ['required', 'min:3']
        ]);

        // submitted search term
        $searchTerm = $request->search_query;

        // categories
        $categories = HelpCenterCategory::all();

        // if validation fails
        if ($validated->fails() === true) {

            $articles = HelpCenter::latest()
                ->paginate(24);

            // return
            return view('siteadmin.help.help', [
                'articles' => $articles,
                'categories' => $categories,
            ])
                ->with('error', 'Someting went wrong with your search.') // not working
                ->withInput(); // is giving me following error: Undefined array key 0
        }

        //
        // if validation do not fail
        if ($validated->fails() === false) {

            $articles = HelpCenter::where('headline', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(2);
            $articles->appends($request->all());


            // return
            return view('siteadmin.help.help', [
                'articles' => $articles,
                'categories' => $categories,
            ])
                ->with('success', 'Found xx results.') // not working
                ->withInput(); // is giving me following error: Undefined array key 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `view`

Answer (score 0):

You can use session messages to return the message before loading the view. So the code will look like this. For more info about sessions [see the documentation](https://lukasmarkevicius.com/blog/how-to-create-session-flash-messages-in-laravel).

```
Session::flash('success','Found Results'); 
return view('...')->withInput();
```